# How to get the search keyword details from google client API

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-client

I need to display  my google analytics search keywords details using google client API  PHP. I have used following code to get those details .

```
$optParams = array('dimensions' => 'ga:searchKeyword','max-results' => '10','sort' => '-ga:users','start-index' => $start + 1 );
$selected_val = "ga:users";

$analytics->data_ga->get('ga:' . $profile_id,$sdate,$edate,$select_gvalues,$optParams);
```

> Its provided empty result.